# JQuery/JS Dropdown Value Handling - Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, datepicker, html-select

I have Datepicker working, but my problem is the coding of the options.

I'm trying to take the date that the user picks, split it up into multiple values, and send those numbers into hidden dropdown boxes that are more acceptable to the eCommerce software that this site uses. I'm fairly new at using Javascript and jQuery, so this may be something small I just haven't thought to try yet.

I keep getting the error in the Chrome console for 'Unexpected Token, "}"'. But when I remove it, it gives me 'Unexpected Token, ")"'. An so on.

Any help or input is greatly appreciated.

jQuery Options:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
               changeMonth: true,
               changeYear: true,minDate: "+7d",
               altField: "#EventDateYear",
               altFormat: "yy",
               onClose: function(dateText,picker){
                  $('#EventDateDay').val( dateText.split(///)[1] );
                  $('#EventDateMonth').val( dateText.split(///)[0] );

    });

 });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" style="display:none;">

<div class="Value" id="event-dropdown">
<select id="EventDateMonth" name="EventDate[Mth]" class="CalendarSelectSmall" style="margin-bottom:3px; %%GLOBAL_EventDateMonthStyle%%">
            <option value="-1">---</option>
                <option value="01">Jan</option>
                <option value="02">Feb</option>
                <option value="03">Mar</option>
                <option value="04">Apr</option>
                <option value="05">May</option>
                <option value="06">Jun</option>
                <option value="07">Jul</option>
                <option value="08">Aug</option>
                <option value="09">Sep</option>
                <option value="10">Oct</option>
                <option value="11">Nov</option>
                <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>
<select id="EventDateDay" name="EventDate[Day]" class="CalendarSelectSmall" style="margin-bottom:3px; %%GLOBAL_EventDateDayStyle%%">
            <option value="-1">---</option>
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
<select id="EventDateYear" name="EventDate[Yr]" class="CalendarSelectSmall" style="margin-bottom:3px; %%GLOBAL_EventDateYearStyle%%">
            %%GLOBAL_OverviewToYears%%
        </select>
          <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("event-dropdown").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("datepicker").style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing the closing curly bracket "}" for the onClose function specified.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script as below,

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true,minDate: "+7d",
           altField: "#EventDateYear",
           altFormat: "yy",
           onClose: function(dateText,picker){
              $('#EventDateDay').val( dateText.split('/')[1] );
              $('#EventDateMonth').val( dateText.split('/')[0] );
           }

});
```

Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/RT67w/) here for working code.

Comment: Now it seems to be giving me this error.

    "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'"

is this due to not having the Datepicker installed correctly?

Comment: Did you check http://jsfiddle.net/skram/RT67w/ ? It is working correctly in jsFiddle.